# Why are there Uppercase Named Patterns in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

In [The F# 4.0 Language Specification](http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.0/FSharpSpec-4.0-latest.pdf), it said that:

> **7.2 Named Patterns**
>
> If ***long-ident*** is more than one-character long or begins with an uppercase character (that is, if **System.Char.IsUpperInvariant** is **true** and **System.Char.IsLowerInvariant** is **false** on the first character), it is resolved by using *Name Resolution in Patterns* (§14.1.6). This algorithm produces one of the following:
>
> - A union case
> - An exception label
> - An active pattern case name
> - A literal value

So the following code will not work:

```
[<Literal>]
let zero = 0

let matchZero = function
    | zero -> printfn "Is %A" zero
    | _ -> printfn "Not 0"
```

The `zero` should be used with a module, or has first uppercase letter `Z`:

```
module Match =
    [<Literal>]
    let zero = 0

let matchZero = function
    | Match.zero -> printfn "Is %A" Match.zero
    | _ -> printfn "Not 0"

///////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////

[<Literal>]
let Zero = 0

let matchZero = function
    | Zero -> printfn "%A" Zero
    | _ -> printfn "Not 0"
```

Why must the literal `zero` have the first uppercase letter to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how the language was designed. There is no use asking "why", there is no underlying reason for it other than the compiler saying that it must.

The *rationale* behind the decision could be the following: when matching a pattern, the compiler needs to somehow figure out whether you're trying to match a specific value or match *any* value and bind it to a name. Consider the following:

```
match 1 with
| zero -> printfn "Zero!"
| x -> printfn "Got a value: %d" x
```

What is the principal difference between `x` and `zero` in this context? To the compiler, they look exactly the same. So when the compiler needs to make a decision whether to generate code like `if 1 = zero then printfn "Zero!"` or to generate code like `let x = 1; printfn "Got a value: %d" x`, what would be the basis for making this decision? How to tell the `x` case from the `zero` case?

So, an artificial basis was invented: if the pattern is capitalized, then it's the `zero`-case, and if it starts with a lower-case character, then it's the `x`-case.

NOTE: When the literal is inside a module, this ambiguity does not arise at all, because there is only one way to interpret a pattern that contains a dot.

**Q:** But couldn't the compiler just look at whether `zero` is actually defined above, and then make the decision based on that?

**A:** Well, yes, it could (and in fact, that's exactly what it does, that's why you get a compile-time warning), but that would lead to unforeseen consequences: when you first write the match, you have `zero` defined, and the `match` expression will only match zeroes. But later in your program evolution somebody decides to remove `zero` for some reason, and now the `match` expression will match anything, *and not produce any compile-time errors*! You will have a subtle bug, which won't be caught by the compiler, so your only hope is for your unit tests or QA people. Preventing this kind of thing from happening is well worth the minor inconvenience of forced naming practices.